# AngularJS ui-grid Get All grid data for Export

Tags: javascript, angularjs, export-to-excel, angular-ui-grid

I need to have all data from `ui-grid` for exporting it to excel.

I know it has already export function with all options like pdf, excel etc.

I have a requirement to export it from our side. for that I need to have all data visible right now on grid.

I am not able to find out how to take data from ui-grid. I have multiple grids that's why I am not able to get `$scope.gridapi`

suggest something on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar situation.
Lets assume we have two grids $scope.workflowGroup and $scope.workflowDetails.

you can get their data:

```
$scope.workflowGroup.data
$scope.workflowDetails.data
```

In case you need all the selected data,

```
$scope.filteredRows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.workflowGroup);
```

Hope this helps.